# Credential manager

Tags: web-apps, password-manager

I'm looking for good credential manager which can be accessed trough the browser, can have a desktop app too. Must have folder sharing so my colleagues can reach them too.The only software I could managed to find is LastPass was recently they were hacked.

Comment: 1) That Lastpass 'hack' did not in any way compromise them. 2) The fact that you have not found others is that you should search on *password manager* 3) What OS, what price?